# How to use Java's map get() method in c#

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, hashmap

i have a given task to translate Java code to C#.

This is the following Java code:

```
public void addEdge(String node1, String node2) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
        map.put(node1, adjacent);
    }
    adjacent.add(node2);
}
```

Here is my C# code:

```
 public void addEdge(string node1, string node2) {
    if (map.ContainsKey(node1)){
        OrderedSet<string> adjacent = map[node1];
        if (adjacent == null)
        {
            adjacent = new OrderedSet<string>();
            map.Add(node1, adjacent);
        }
        adjacent.Add(node2);
    }
       else
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Key {0} was not found", node1));               
}
```

When i run the program i get the following exception:
"The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Where is my mistake?

**EDIT1:**
Here i have declared map:

```
private Dictionary<string, OrderedSet<string>> map = new Dictionary<string, OrderedSet<string>>();
```

**EDIT2:**
I get the exception in the following line:

```
map.Add(node1, adjacent);
```

Comment: Is this your actual code or an attempt to summarize the issue? I don't see `map` declared anywhere and your guards should prevent that Exception. And are you sure that the Exception is occurring in this method?

Comment: Attempt to summarize the issue. I declared it above the method

Comment: Maybe it's something with TryGetValue instead of ContainsKey..but i'm not sure how to use it

Comment: Step through in the debugger, see which line it's being thrown from

Comment: check out @Esteban Falcón answer for your second edit

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why will you get *The given key was not present in the dictionary* exception, but you should change:

```
map.Add(node1, adjacent);
```

to:

```
map[node1] = adjacent;
```

The Add method will throw an Exception if you try to add a key that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

stupid Vote Down, true code is

```
public void addEdge(string node1, string node2) {
        OrderedSet<string> adjacent = map.ContainsKey(node1) ? map[node1] : null;
        if (adjacent == null)
        {
            adjacent = new OrderedSet<string>();
            map.Add(node1, adjacent);
        }
        adjacent.Add(node2);            
}
```

and it worked fine

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert bool to OrderedSet<String>

Comment: if(adjacent==null) {
    adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
    map.put(node1, adjacent);
}
if not contains node1 add it and put node2 to its adjacent

Answer (score 0):

get method in Java equivalent in C#
map.ContainsKey(node1) ? map[node1] : null;